# How check string starts with number, period(.) and space in XSLT

Tags: regex, xslt-2.0

I want to check string starts with `number`, `period(.)` and `space`. For doing that I used `regex` but that not gives the correct answer.

Input:

```
<para>
    <text>1. this a paragaraph1</text>
    <text>12. this a paragaraph2</text>
    <text>this a paragaraph3</text>
</para>
```

Output should be:

```
<result>
    <para type="number">1. this a paragaraph1</para>
    <para type="number">12. this a paragaraph2</para>
    <para type="not number">this a paragaraph3</para>
</result>
```

Explanation of the logic:

You can see `para/text` has a string. Some of them are starting with numbers (`1.`  , `12.` ) then `.` and space. At that time `para/@type` must be `number`. You can see the 1st and 2nd `<text>` elements pass that condition. Then that `@type` must be `number`. other wise `not number`. just like 3rd `<text>` element

Tried code:

```
<xsl:template match="text">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="matches(.,'[[0-9]+]')">
            <para type="number">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </para>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <para type="not number">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </para>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="para">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anchor the regular expression at the start of the string with `^` and use a simpler syntax e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="text[matches(., '^[0-9]+')]">
  <para type="number">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </para>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This answer selects only numbers. not `.` and `space` after the numbers. How can I solve that problem?

Comment: I change your regex to `matches(., '^[0-9]+. ')` but then it selects `1. text` and `1: text` both. But the expected result should be only `1. text`

Comment: Well, your original attempt doesn't include any dot or space, I corrected the lack of the `^` anchor to look only at the start at the string and the double use of square brackets. If you expect a dot and a space after the digits then use `'^[0-9]+\. '`